# Is there a function to change the name of a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an equivalent of `DataFrame.rename(columns = newcolumns)` for Series? I am imagining something like

```
def rename(self, name = None):
    self.name = name
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure why this has recieved a downvote. I think this is a reasonable thing to wonder about. I prefer to program in a functional style, avoiding statements like `myseries.name = "newname"` wherever possible. This style of programming is generally well-supported in the Pandas API, (e.g. `inplace=False` by default in most functions), and I am just wondering whether there is a way of updating Series names in a functional way which I have just missed. (Otherwise I will submit a feature request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

As of most recent [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html#pandas.Series.rename) the method `Series.rename`, when passed a *scalar*, does exactly what you want; returns a new series with **new name**.

What follows is was true at sometime, but not relevant anymore.

#### Previous post

I stumbled across this problem myself and have found it very frustrating that the API does not cover the use case of changing `Series.name` in a method-chaining fashion.

I have found two awkward work-around to this.

1. If the series in question is a result of reducing columns (row values) of a data-frame, i.e., calling apply on a data frame with a function that returns a scalar,

   ```
   # this returns a series where series.name == df.index.name, not what we want.
   df.apply(lambda row: series-to-scalar(row),axis=1)
   ```

   you can either transform the data-frame using `DataFrame.apply` by having `func` return a single value series indexed by the **new name** then access the column using `[]`.

   ```
   df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(series-to-scalar(row),index=['new name']),axis=1)['new name']
   ```

   or add a new column named **new name** to the data-frame then access the column using `[]`.

   ```
   df.assign(**{'new name': lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: row-to-scalar(row),axis=1)})['new name']
   ```
2. If you have no control on where the series came from and you need to chain methods to change its name, use `Series.pipe` to create a new series frow the original series with a **new name**.

   ```
   sr.pipe(lambda sr: pd.Series(sr,name='new name'))
   ```

Hope this helps. And good luck with the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need rename function for Pandas.Series, pd.Series has two rename methods: [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) and [rename_axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html?highlight=rename_axis#pandas.Series.rename_axis) but none of them satisfied your wishes. You could change name of the Series in common style:

```
e = pd.Series(np.arange(10), name='test')
In [95]: e
Out[95]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
Name: test, dtype: int32

e.name = 'new'
In [97]: e
Out[97]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
Name: new, dtype: int32
```

But if you need functional style you need to do request for that feature in future realeses (it seems that it's very easy to implement, just add one keyword for `.rename` method).